# SharePoint check in SPListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, wss

In sharepoint how can you check in an SPListItem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See on MSDN: [SPListItem.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.file.aspx).**[CheckIn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467428.aspx)**;

*For example:*

```
SPFile file = item.File;
if (file.CheckOutStatus != SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
{
    file.CheckIn("Reason for check in.", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}
```

The optional second parameter allows specification of either minor, major or overwrite check in via the [SPCheckinType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcheckintype.aspx).

Comment: is there any necessity to forcefully publish the item in a document library using file.publish("published by system") ?

Comment: @SaMolPP That's going to depend on the settings of the library.  Some will auto-publish on checkin, if they're not configured to use publishing, and others will require publishing to be...published.

Answer (score 4):

Great response, however in 2010, CheckOutStatus is declining - use SPCheckOutType instead. You might also want to Approve the item as well - for example:

```
SPList MyLib = TheWeb.Lists["MyLibrary"];
if (MyLib != null)
{
    if (MyLib.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(SPListItem AnItem in MyLib.Items)
        {
              SPFile TheFile = AnItem.File;
              if (TheFile.CheckOutType != SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
              {
                   TheFile.CheckIn("Check in comment", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                   TheFile.Approve("Approval comment");
              }
        }
    }
}
```

David M. Sterling
SICG

Comment: but this will result in modified by as  "system account" .how to change  tis , inside a item event receiver

Comment: Impersonate the user account is one way.

Comment: Another way is to set the Author and Editor field prior (remember to use the fully qualified name - i.e.  i:0#.w|<domain>\<user account>. You HAVE to set BOTH fields and do an update.

Comment: Can you pls provide ,how to implement this , using C# .  a bit of code...